When is a finitely generated commutative algebra a projective module over its invariant subalgebra?
For the sake of simplicity, I will work over the complex numbers.
Let $A$ be a finitely generated algebra and $G$ any finite group of algebra automorphisms. Then, by Noether's Theorem, $A^G$ is also a finitely generated algebra, and $A$ is a finitely generated $A^G$-module.
Under what conditions will $A$ be also a projective module?
In the case $A$ is a polynomial algebra, the answer is well known due to Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem: $G$ must act as a complex reflection group.
And what about general $A$ and $G$? Are there general results, or other important special cases, where the answer is known (like, possibly, algebras of Laurent polynomials?)

I feel I should point out that the problem with Laurent polynomials in several variables is that linear automorphisms on the variables don't extend to automorphisms on Laurent polynomials.

A sufficient condition is that the cardinality of all the orbits is same.

@DaveBenson yes, you are right.... do you know of any multiplicative invarian theory result?
